# Is there any SQL Server studio managment and redgate sqlcompare/datacompare like tools for MySQL?

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for SQL Server studio management-like and redgate sqlcompare/datacompare-like tools for MySQL.

What have you used that is as close to these tools or better for MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com)
This is the best I found for free. It is not as powerful as SSMS, but it better than viewing 30 columns in mysql's console. ;D

Answer (score 0):

Very nice one with free version available: [**dbForge Studio for MySQL**](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).
[Other tools there](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/) (Compare Bundle, Schema Compare, Data Compare etc.)